# Irreducibility of polynomial P(X) = X

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have the following exercise:

Let $R$ be the integral domain of all polynomials $P(X)$ with real coefficients whose constant term is a rational.
Is the poly $P(X) = X$ irreducible in $R$?

My question is: Is this similar to showing that $P(X+c)$ is irreducible if and only if $P(X)$ is irreducible. I do not understand the role on the constant term being rational.

Comment: But isn't a poly of degree 1 a unit. Hence a unit is not irreducible?

Comment: The only units in $\mathbb R[x]$ are the non-zero constants.  Not the degree $1$ polynomials.  Can't invert them.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Be careful. The ambient ring is important. In $K[T^2,T^3]$ (a subring of $K[T]$), the polynomial $T^3$ is irreducible. Also, it should not be omitted that irreducible elements are required to be non-zero and non-invertible. This is why we have to determine the units as well.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Also, the correct Wikipedia article here is this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element

Comment: It does not disprove the statement. But (as you can also see from my answer) stating that polynomials of degree $1$ are irreducible is **not enough**, since the ring in question is not the full polynomial ring - it is a ring of polynomials. My example just shows by analogy that we need to distinguish these cases properly.

Comment: No. You are forgetting that the units may differ. $2X \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is irreducible, but it is reducible in the subring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Thus, the statement "If a polynomial is irreducible in $K[X]$, then it is irreducible in all subrings it contains" is wrong. (All my comments refer to comments by Jean-Claude which have been deleted. Sorry if this is confusing.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ah, yes, units. I did miss something important. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First, observe $\mathbb{R}[X]^{\times} = \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ and $R^{\times} = \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$. Notice that $X$ is a non-zero non-unit in $R$. If $X = A \cdot B$ with $A,B \in R$, this equation also holds in $\mathbb{R}[X]$. Since $X$ is irreducible there, we get $A \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ or  $B \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$. The claim now follows  from $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \cap R = \mathbb{Q}^{\times} = R^{\times}$.

Comment: How can I prove that $\mathbb{R}[X]^{\times} = \mathbb{R}^{\times}$?

Comment: I am sure that you will find the proof of $K[X]^{\times} = K^{\times}$ (where $K$ is a field, or just an integral domain) in your algebra textbook and via a simple google search ("units of polynomial ring") and of course also here on MSE.